# How can I check if counter cache is working okay?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, counter-cache

I've done everything what it says on Railscast( http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column ).

I've done with those setups

- migration to add new column 'comments_count' to 'community_topics" table, which is parent table.
- I've added **counter_cache: true** to models/comment.rb (Now it's just like this   **belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, counter_cache: true** )

and I have this in my view

> <%= community_topic.comment_threads.size %>

As you know, I can't see any difference on its appearance.
How can I know if counter cache is working fine now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the RailsCast you reference, you should verify by checking the SQL that is being run via the logs. Before the counter cache you should get a SQL `COUNT` query something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "comment_threads" WHERE ("comment_threads".commentable_id = 61)
```

and after you should not see one, and instead only see the CommunityTopic loading:

```
SELECT * FROM "comment_threads" WHERE id = 61
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking at logs in development.log but there all the sql command looks almost the same. It contains **COUNT** so which means counter cache is not working. right?

Comment: Only if the `COUNT` queries are for the table that you added the cache for, and the counter cache on the parent table exists and has a value.

Comment: Now I got it!! I was thinking I once you set up for counter cache, the number will be returned even if you put something like **<%= parent.children.size %>** but I'm supposed to put **<%= parent.comments_count %>**  am I right?

Comment: @Foo Nope, `parent.children.size` should work. Counter cache is meant to be seamless.

Comment: Do you think the reason why it won't work is because I'm using polymorphic children, which is created automatically by the gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'? Does it matter if I put **<%= parent.comments_count %>** it looks working fine.